# AOSP building error

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I was trying to compile `Android O code` on `Linux 16.04 LTS` machine but I'm facing some issues. I'm stuck on the following error:

```
[ 89% 55834/62176] Compiling SDK Stubs:
out/target/comm.../android_system_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 
[ 89% 55835/62176] Compiling SDK Stubs: out/target/comm...BRARIES/android_stubs_current_intermediates/classes.jar
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. 
20:33:13 ninja failed with: exit status 1 build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed make: *** 
[run_soong_ui] Error 1
```

I tried installing the following libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

But the issue remains same. Could anyone please help to resolve this?

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu >= 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip
```